# Comparing mysql record with current time

Tags: php

I have a query that shows appointments that a user has made in a format year-month-day start time(00:00:00) end time(00:00:00),now i want to compare this whole format with the current time and if it is equal or higher to not show do appointment because user has the option to cancel the appointment and if the time for the appointment has passed i want to hide the cancel appointment option from him...here is my query and html echo...

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id,date,start,end FROM jos_jxtc_appbook_appointments WHERE userident='$idusera'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
echo '<div class="record" id="record-',$row['id'],'">
    <a href="?delete=',$row['id'],'" class="delete">Delete</a>
    <strong>',$row['date'], $row['start'], $row['end'],'</strong>
  </div>';
}
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used this query and it is working now as i wanted to...

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT id,date,start,end FROM jos_jxtc_appbook_appointments WHERE userident='$idusera' AND CONCAT(date,' ',start)> DATE_ADD( NOW( ) , INTERVAL 6 HOUR )");
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
 {

 echo '<div class="record" id="record-',$row['id'],'">
    <a href="?delete=',$row['id'],'" class="delete">Delete</a>
    <strong>',$row['date'],$space,$row['start'],$space,$row['end'],'</strong>
  </div>';

 }
```

this part DATE_ADD( NOW( ) , INTERVAL 6 HOUR ) is because time_zone in the mysql is different then mine(-6) and because i cant change timezone in the mysql directly(because i dont have super privileges).

Answer (score 0):

Aside from not using `mysql_` functions, just use time functions to do the comparison:

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE timeColumn > CURTIME()
```

See [Date and Time Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Comment: if i do this query will this remove my passed appointment in real time?or i have to do it with ajax or something like that?

Comment: It will do it in realtime (based on `CURTIME()`)

Comment: i am using this query "SELECT id,date,start,end FROM jos_jxtc_appbook_appointments WHERE userident='$idusera' AND date<=CURDATE() start<=CURTIME()" and i cant get it to work...it doesnt echo anything now...

Comment: I don't know what your data or your table looks like.